# Wordpress PHP - Hide posts if users aren't friends

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am using a wordpress plugin which adds functionality to my site letting the user add new friends etc. There is a specific function defined in the PHP file which lets you check if users are friends. The code for this function is here:

```
/**
 * Utility function to determine is a user is friends with another user.
 *
 * @since 1.2.3
 *
 * @param
 * tmp_uid - int - Current user ID
 * tmp_friend_uid - int - Friend user ID
 * @return returns the value of 'friend_approved' field. 1 - Approved, 0 - Pending, null - no status
 */
function friends_check_status($tmp_uid, $tmp_friend_uid) {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT friend_approved FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix
        . "friends WHERE user_ID = %d AND friend_user_ID = %d", $tmp_uid, $tmp_friend_uid);
    //echo "sql=[". $sql ."]<br />";
    return $wpdb->get_var($sql);
}
```

I would like to run this function to check against `author_id` to check if the post author and user are friends. If they are friends they should be able to view the post, if they aren't friends with the author the post should be hidden. Could I simply substitute `tmp_friend_uid` for `the_author_meta( 'ID' );` or something?

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but OP could explain what he tried to do to resolve this. He could also try to do what he suggested to see whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could copy / modify the function (into say your theme's functions.php file) - do NOT modify the plugin files - an update will wipe your changes.

So, in your theme's functions.php file, put this in with these modifications:

```
function friends_post_author_status($tmp_uid) {
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $post_author_id = $post->post_author;

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT friend_approved FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix
        . "friends WHERE user_ID = %d AND friend_user_ID = %d", $tmp_uid, $post_author_id);
    //echo "sql=[". $sql ."]<br />";
    return $wpdb->get_var($sql);
}
```

Then, in your loop, you can access this function and detect if the post author is a friend:

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$is_friend = friends_post_author_status($user_ID);
if ( $is_friend ) {
    // ... do stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks and is there any wp function to check for post authors on a page full of posts? so to essentially only show posts from users who you are friends with. Could you just hide the posts or is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: That would be possible, but not exactly simple.  You'd want to use a custom [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), to find all the "Friend" authors, then use the [author__in](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) parameter.  This is beyond the scope of an answer on SO, though.

Comment: Ok thanks. I may have to look at using something more simple then such as  adding display: none to the article or something. Would that work?